# Mimic or imitate the animation on hidesbaronswipe on navigation bar to custom view

Tags: ios, swift, uiview, uinavigationbar, uianimation

I wish to implement the animated hide and show like how the navigation bar hidesbaronswipe behaviour. I cant get any more information on the internet and I decided to consult here, kindly guide me on how to do that. Thanks.

P.S. I did the animate whole view by changing the height constant of the view but the whole animation is not smooth enough.

the code that I tried :

```
func scrollViewDidScroll(_ scrollView: UIScrollView) {

    if currentOffset > scrollView.contentOffset.y {

        for button in topButton{
            button.isHidden = false
        }

        self.topbuttonStackHeight.constant = 50
        topButtonStack.isHidden = false

    }
    else if currentOffset < scrollView.contentOffset.y - 50{

        self.topbuttonStackHeight.constant = 0
        self.topButtonStack.isHidden = true

    }


}
```

Comment: Show us your code, what have you tried.

Comment: @franiis post updated